# SQL Group by data on different columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using a relational database where I have data like below:

```
messages        sender    receiver
[1,2,3]      |    A     |    B
[4,5,6]      |    C     |    D
[7,8,9]      |    D     |    C
[10,11,12]   |    B     |    A
```

I need to group separate messages in a full conversation like this:

```
conversation                 participant_1    particiapant_2
[1,2,3, 10, 11, 12]      |        A         |        B          -- order of participants does not matter
[4,5,6, 7,8,9]           |        C         |        D
```

Two solutions came to my mind that I think would work:

1. Flipping the columns sender and receiver and creating a temporary table, unioning that with the original table so the table would look like this:

```
messages         p_1        p_2
[1,2,3]      |    A     |    B
[4,5,6]      |    C     |    D
[7,8,9]      |    D     |    C
[10,11,12]   |    B     |    A
[1,2,3]      |    B     |    A
[4,5,6]      |    D     |    C
[7,8,9]      |    C     |    D
[10,11,12]   |    A     |    B
```

And finally grouping by p_1 or p_2 and using and aggregate function on the array of elements would yield the result.

2. The second solution is to assign a special id to to a conversation and if sender and receiver and receiver and sender are equal, like this:

```
messages        sender    receiver      id
[1,2,3]      |    A     |    B       |   1
[4,5,6]      |    C     |    D       |   2
[7,8,9]      |    D     |    C       |   2
[10,11,12]   |    B     |    A       |   1
```

Grouping by id would make me use an aggregate function in the sender and receiver columns because the grouping would fail otherwise. So I think solution 1 would work better.

However, I don't know how to express these solutions in SQL quite well. Or is there is a better and more optimized solution to this? If so how can you come around a problem like this?

EDIT: The schema of the original table is like this:

```
message             from           to         message_sid
"message 1"     |     A       |     B      |   "SM716241"  
"message 2"     |     A       |     B      |   "SM762415"
"test"          |     B       |     A      |   "SM723741"
reply           |     C       |     D      |   "SM142469"
```

The query I made to bring it in the form of the first table is this:

```
select json_agg(json_build_object('message', body, 'date', date_sent, 'direction', direction)),
       message.from as sender,
       message.to   as receiver
from message
group by message.from, message.to;
```

I put a more simplified version of the schema to make it easier to understand. The query includes dates and message direction as well (inbound or outbound) but they are not essential to the question.

Comment: What type is `messages`? Either way you should consider normalizing the schema first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the fact that 'A' < 'B' to swap them over like:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN sender < receiver THEN sender ELSE receiver END as participant1,
  CASE WHEN sender < receiver THEN receiver ELSE sender END as participant2
```

then do your string concatting of your message ids (or however it is that your messages are stored,  I didn't quite understand the presentation of the messageids in the question). This means you don't need a heavy "x/y union y/x" to achieve a consistent "list of the conversation parties"

Also, in PGSQL you have GREATEST and LEAST functions that can achieve the same thing:

```
SELECT
  LEAST(sender, receiver) as participant1,
  GREATEST(sender, receiver) as participant2
```

---

```
select json_agg(json_build_object('message', body, 'date', date_sent, 'direction', direction)),
       GREATEST(message.from,message.to) as party1,
       LEAST(message.from,message.to) as party2
from message
group by GREATEST(message.from, message.to), LEAST(message.from, message.to) ;
```

Comment: I updated the question if that helps and gives a better idea. I will try to implement your solution.

Comment: You should just be able to modify the original query that you used to generate the json: add GREATEST/LEAST as I showed and group by them. The CASE WHEN route can be slightly more flexible because you can return a different value from it if you need, but in this case the simple approach may be better

Answer (score 0):

use Inner join and concatenate message, then select only half of message, If you have duplicate sender and receiver then First group message into into comaseprate rows then  perform inner join

```
select '1,2,3' as messages , 'A' as  sender, 'B' as receiver into #temp
union all
select '4,5,6', 'C' , 'D'
union all
select '7,8,9', 'D' , 'C'
union all
select '10,11,12', 'B' , 'A'

declare @totalrow int=0
select  t1.messages+','+t2.messages as messages1  ,t1.sender,t1.receiver into #temp2
 from #temp t1 inner join #temp t2 on t1.sender=t2.receiver
 set @totalrow = @@rowcount

select top (@totalrow/2) * 
 from #temp2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  '1,2,3' AS messages,
  'A' AS sender,
  'B' AS receiver INTO #temp
UNION ALL
SELECT
  '4,5,6',
  'C',
  'D'
UNION ALL
SELECT
  '7,8,9',
  'D',
  'C'
UNION ALL
SELECT
  '10,11,12',
  'B',
  'A'

DECLARE @totalrow int = 0
SELECT
  t1.messages + ',' + t2.messages AS messages1,
  t1.sender,
  t1.receiver INTO #temp2
FROM #temp t1
INNER JOIN #temp t2
  ON t1.sender = t2.receiver
SET @totalrow = @@rowcount

SELECT TOP (@totalrow / 2)
  *
FROM #temp2
```